# how to avoid duplicating value with all fields in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
Select * from V_Receipt Where F_Exhibition='11000' order by F_Exhibitor_Name
```

When executed I get duplicate values, how can I resolve this.

Comment: Try using `DISTINCT`?

Comment: i want to get all values from that table.so how i can use Distinct

Comment: @jasemhi Look at my answer, you can use distinct but you have to explicitly define each field

Comment: have a look at W3School distinct use link:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DISTINCT` but you will also have to explicitly define each field

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, field3 /* etc etc */ 
FROM V_Receipt 
WHERE F_Exhibition = '11000' 
ORDER BY F_Exhibitor_Name DESC
```

Comment: What's the problem if use `DISTINCT *` for all value?

Comment: You cant use `DISTINCT *` as you need to specify each field when using distinct

Comment: I don't get it, `DISTINCT *` is a valid statement for SQL server

Answer (score -2):

```
with cte 
as
(select row_number(partition by feild 1 order by field1) as rnk,* from V_Receipt )
select * from cte where rnk=1;
```